# Finding p.d.f. of a function of random variable which is exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, density-function, random-functions

> Given random random variable $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, find p.d.f of $Y=\ln(X)$

### Approach

I decided to go the cumulative distribution route. I take integral of p.d.f. of $X$ with $y$:

$$F(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \lambda \exp(-\lambda \cdot x) = -\exp(-\lambda \cdot \ln(x)) + 1=1 - y^{-\lambda}.$$

Then, take first derivative

$$f_Y(y)=F'(y)=\lambda y^{-\lambda}.$$

But the answer is completely different:

$$f_Y(y)=\lambda e^{y-\lambda e^{t}}.$$

*(I changed variable letters of the answer to match letters in my solution, hopefully I didn't mess up anything)*

**Question**

Where did I make a mistake? Did I do something completely wrong?

I've checked the integraion with integral calculator, but it seems to be correct.

Comment: This is my first try in mathjax, hopefully I didn't mess anything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've miscalculated $F$ to start with.  Here's a hint:  $$F(y) = P[Y \leq y] = P[\ln(X) \leq y] = P[X \leq e^y]$$

Comment: Thanks! I've off by one error, but I'll figure it out. Probably I've applied chain rule incorrectly. Should I edit the question to put a new approach or should I just leave it as it is? Also, thanks for some mathjax best practices.

Comment: @Incomputable, happy to help on both fronts!  It's typically best to leave the question as is, and if you edit it, you should only add a portion (rather than replace stuff).  If you want to edit it to add a more complete solution, it's totally up to you; some people like to do that, but it's not required or even expected.